# Can I ask this non-puzzle question?

Tags: discussion

Ever since I found this site a few weeks ago (through stackoverflow) I've been on here for multiple hours a day. Problem is, I can't solve or create anything.
I am looking for other novice PSE lurkers who stare at puzzles and only come up with fragments. I'd like to create a discord group or something similar to work on **PSE puzzles** together and maybe even create some. I doubt too many (new) people read the meta posts (me included), so I was wondering if I can post such a post on the main site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No.

Questions on the main site must be either puzzles or questions about puzzles. At their core, they must be *actual questions* that have an answer. Your "question" would be using the PSE homepage as a "forum", and that is antithetical to the site's philosophy.

You'll often find people collaborating on recent puzzles in [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) - to work with other people on a solve, I recommend you go there. You can also make a separate room for that specific puzzle and drop a link in TSL.

If you're worried about people stealing what you've written to "answer-snipe" you, then you should know that there's really nothing to worry about. TSL regulars are all very friendly people -- there's a mutual understanding that stealing other people's work towards an answer is a Thing You Should Not Do.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I scrolled a bit through TSL and saw no puzzle solving except for your CCCC's. I tried to get something going but that didn't work either so I think I'll try to contact people some other way. Might stop by when I have a more specific problem that doen't require brainstorm-ish discussion. I wasn't afraid of TSL sniping btw, I classify that as a "confined group".

Comment: @RnRoger - did you? I can't find that message, but I guess I must have missed it. In any case, we do brainstorm-ish discussion in TSL fairly often - it's just been quiet the past few weeks for some reason.

Comment: I'll just keep tuned in to the chat then ^^

Comment: "*TSL regulars are all very friendly people*" Well ... I heard there's this one guy who's really *devious* ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Notes for new puzzlers:

**Meta Puzzles**:

It is perfectly acceptable to ask for help in creating puzzles and make joint puzzles with others if you do not feel confident!

**Partials**:

Found a little bit of a big puzzle? Post a partial answer explaining your answers. Not all answers need to be complete. Partials can give you or others inspiration for the final parts.

**Chat**:

[The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) is a great place for new users. You can:

- Ask for advice
- Ask for someone to review a puzzle and give feedback
- Discuss findings with others and maybe join in with solving puzzles with community wikis

The more you post and talk to others the more experience you gain. With experience comes speed answering questions and better quality questions.

Don't worry - everyone has to start at the bottom here.

Re: your question:

You could create a community wiki puzzle created by low rep users and to be solved *only* by low rep users?

Comment: I am aware of partial answers, I usually don't even get close to that though. More like a clue to a hint that might be a fragment of a partial answer. Yeah. The large amount of users and the discussing of things other than actual puzzles makes the PSE chat rooms seem suboptimal for brainstorming, which is what I had in mind monstly. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @RnRoger  the chat is unusually busy atm. But usually its quite quiet. You could create a separate room. Brainstorming isn't usually  a good idea because then people know how to solve

Comment: @Beatly Gerbil With brainstorming I meant in a confined group, working together and knowing nobody will 'snipe' the question. I'll try using the lair for a bit first and decide later.

Comment: @RnRoger ask a mod to make a private room for you? You need to find people first

Comment: This answer, while seemingly useful, isn't really an *answer* to the question. You even note at the bottom of the posted answer that most of it is irrelevant.

Comment: @RnRoger "More like a clue to a hint that might be a fragment of a partial answer." - :) :) :) Someone at **my** level !!!! :) :) :)

Comment: @YowE3K Have I found my first puzzle solving buddy? ;o

Comment: @RnRoger Probably not - I never have the time to collaborate on anything, especially due to time-zone differences (I am meant to be working at the moment!  Shhh - don't tell my boss!!)

Comment: @YowE3K You got that gold badge some way! Collaborating doesn't have to be real time converstation but could also be forwarding ideas or anything. Plenty of puzzles that don't get solved for days. I won't press you if you don't want to though. (What are timezones? I sleep and puzzle when I damn well please >;) (so usually that is about 4 hours of sleep per n̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ morning))

Comment: @RnRoger LOL - The gold badge was due to the compulsive behaviour associated with my autism - I just kept logging in every day for over 100 days because I had logged in the day before and I didn't want to break the "streak". And then I think I forgot one day, which broke the "I have to do this or else I will stop my 'streak' " need to do it, so I have been fairly infrequent since then.

Comment: "It is perfectly acceptable to ask for help in creating puzzles" ... you should specify **on Meta**.

Comment: @NH. No, that wouldn't be on-topic in Meta. It's on-topic in main, however.

Comment: @Erik what is the point of the sandbox, then?

Comment: @NH. (sorry for late reply) The "riddle sandbox" is a failed attempt to make riddles better, the reason being that the answer isn't known at first. Questions about making or solving puzzles should be directly asked on Main. Meta is about Puzzling.SE and Puzzling.Meta themselves, not questions about puzzles.